# Detecting I/Q imbalance

Tags: demodulation, quadrature

Are there any methods of detecting, measuring, and/or estimating I/Q imbalance (from, say, an upstream quadrature mixer and/or ADC), without using or having a controlled test signal (other than whatever the RF antenna is currently picking up).

Comment: Receive or transmit path?

Comment: Receive.  Transmit path is possibly a good topic for someone to ask a separate targeted question.

Comment: ah, by the way, the video I refer students to on the effects of IQ imbalance is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNMOwhEHE6w) GRCon16 presentation by Matt Ettus; it's often a bit "symptomatic", but it does kind of allow one to follow around on how to link strange things happening to one's constellation diagram and the receiver imperfections (IQ imbalance somewhen after 20 minutes into the talk).

Answer (score 4):

As long as the assumption of equiprobable data with independent I and Q reasonably holds (and over the long duration with whitened transmissions this is typically a good assumption), then IQ imbalance is blindly detected by correlating the I and Q paths. The complex result of the complex conjugate product of the I and Q data path is proportional to the IQ quadrature error.  Any DC offset is removed first and amplitude normalization is provided via AGC:

[image: IQ correction]

This correction can be used together with IQ amplitude balancing in a leveling loop that continuously monitors the IQ datapaths when they are active, in which case the "exponential averager" in the diagram above becomes the accumulator (integrator) in a first order loop. (The exponential averager is a "leaky integrator").

I have also developed a novel decision-directed IQ correction technique (I think it's novel as I haven't found it elsewhere yet, but typically whenever I think that, I eventually discover it was done 20 years ago...) that works as depicted in the picture below:

[image: IQ Correction]

$I$, $Q$ represent each complex symbol sample, and $\hat I$, $\hat Q$ represent the closest decision. This treats error in the difference of Q as a phase rotation error (of the entire constellation) and error in the difference of I as the quadrature error measurement (we could swap and work the other way as well, it is simply deciding which is the reference to measure the other). So here we are forcing all the quadrature error to be on Q and using I (the real axis) as the reference. Such decision directed approaches work well under higher SNR conditions (when symbol errors are <1e-2 for example) as any noise on all correct symbol decisions is eliminated in the decision, and that clean decision is used in the measurement.

Here is a demonstration of the technique using a 16QAM constellation with a static phase rotation and quadrature IQ imbalance. The starting constellation is depicted below after being normalized to the rms constellation level, together with the nearest (decisions) constellation points:

[image: 16 QAM with phase rotation and IQ imbalance]

If you look carefully, you will see phantom "decisions" for the upper most and lower most sample where I used a repeating grid that extends beyond the original 16QAM constellation as the possible "nearest decisions". This is part of the algorithm in that the intermediate decision optimally contributes to the phase rotation error measurement. Importantly the standard deviation of the constellation for normalizing the input waveform is done on the original and complete constellation and not these selected decisions and “phantom decisions”.

For reference the full 16 QAM constellation is shown below, which would be the decision samples used above in addition to the two "phantom decision" samples I mentioned:

[image: Constellation]

The correction is applied in two steps concurrently, to remove the rotation and to remove the quadrature error. Below shows the result from a correction loop that removed the rotation only to demonstrate the process, the rotation was removed by minimizing the difference on Q multiplied by the sign of I; the resulting graphic makes it clear how the quadrature error would then be proportional to the average of the difference of the real portion (I) of the samples and their closest decision (multiplied by the sign of Q):

[image: IQ error only]

A simulation of this technique demonstrates fast convergence to accurately determine (and ultimately correct) the quadrature error). Below shows the IQ error measurement under this condition of phase rotation and IQ error where here the phase offset was corrected and the IQ was left open loop to observe the error:

[image: Correction]

As with any other similar blind (no training sequence) technique, there is rotational ambiguity such that this could arbitrarily converge to 0, 90, 180 or 270 degree rotations of the constellation compared to the actual required one. Since there are only 4 possible ambiguities (for QPSK and QAM modulations), this is easily resolved through either the use of a reference header or correct data demodulation when the type of data is known (such as a correct CRC, or other recognizable portion of the message payload).

Answer (score 2):

Yes!

What is done in practice is simply disconnecting (or even better, terminating properly) the RF input of the receiver.

Then, you observe empiric noise variance separately on I and Q, and normalize so that they are equal.

This assumes that NF variations are benign, but it does work. If you can, you'd of course try to increase noise power.

USRP transceiver daughterboards can be RX IQ imbalance calibrated by letting TX transmit pseudowhite noise at a slight frequency offset (to average out potential TX imbalance) and observing the intra-board crosstalk. Same would work for any sufficiently random external signal. If you have a dominant external signal, intentionally tune a bit off, and average enough.

Comment: The stochastic approach is used to do two things:  (1) match variance of I to Q; (2) eliminate cross-correlation between I and Q.  These address gain and phase mismatch, respectively. This presumes that I and Q should have the same power and that they should be uncorrelated as is typically the case. It also typically presumes that the IQ imbalance is memoryless; however, if mismatch is caused by a difference in a baseband filter between I and Q for example, it will have frequency-dependent components. The described approach can still address this but needs a *lot* more data.